# MySQL UDF Lib Install

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-udf

I'm trying to install and use MySql UDF Lib but I'm facing an ELF error on its install procedure.

I'm under Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64.

Tried to follow some others answers and added `-m64` flag for compiler, and still having the error.

Disclaimer: I'm not linux specialist, just trying a solution for a program issue

```
root@server:/usr/lib/mysql/plugin# sh install.sh
Compiling the MySQL UDF
gcc -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /usr/lib/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
MySQL UDF compiled successfully
-e
Please provide your MySQL root password
Enter password:
ERROR 1126 (HY000) at line 29: Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 11 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)
ERROR: unable to install the UDF
root@server:/usr/lib/mysql/plugin#
```

My mysql `file` command:

```
root@server:/usr/bin# file mysql
mysql: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=23996cc38af44cd87dbcde82f46c47f9047769b0, stripped
```

And my lib `file` command:

```
root@server:/usr/lib# file lib_mysqludf_sys.so
lib_mysqludf_sys.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=8bcbe183af9bd452325f14c89810a34c5bfbbedd, not stripped
```

And my mysqld `file` command:

```
root@server:/run/mysqld# file /usr/sbin/mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=eaac3628f59f9bfefceacef50d86d8cb834c0a7a, stripped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late response, but better than never I hope :)

You are installing the plugin to `/usr/lib`

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /usr/lib/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
```

But your MySQL server is only looking for plugins installed on `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin`.

So, changing the above gcc command to

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
```

Should fix the `Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so'` error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Knowledge is never too late. Even if I had to find another solution to keep going, I tried your solution and it worked perfectly. Surely next time I won't struggle. Thanks